# Issue creating a new object in Java and passing it to setMethod

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to create a new object using the parameters passed in, then use that new object to place in the setCarColor method listed below.  But my setCarColor in my constructor is giving an error for my clv variable.  It says "Can not find symbol".  The clv is my variable from the CarColor class.  I'm not sure if it is because the parameters being passed in(rdIn, grnIn, bluIn)are integers or what?  Does anyone have any ideas please?

Best Regards,

```
public abstract class Vehicle 
{
  private String shapeId;
  CarColor carColor;//CarColor data member from the ColorValue.java class


public Shape(String bodyid, int rd, int grn, int ble)
{
 CarColor clv = new CarColor(rdIn, grnIn, bluIn);
 setCarColor(clv(rd, grn, ble));// <---error here
}

private CarColor getCarColor()
{
    return carColor;
}

private void setCarColor(int redIn, int blueIn, int greenIn)
{
if (redIn == 0 || blueIn == 0 || greenIn == 0 )
{
    System.out.println("The value entered in is null.  Please try again ");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is *nearly* fine:

```
ColorValue clv = new ColorValue(rdIn, grnIn, bluIn);
```

... although it *doesn't* populate the `colorValue` field, which is what you might have been expecting, and you don't actually have `rdIn`, `grnIn` and `bluIn` variables. Did you mean `rd`, `grn`, `ble`? (It helps if you *don't* contract names like this, by the way.)

But this line is broken in two ways:

```
setColorValue(clv(rd, grn, ble));
```

Firstly, it's trying to call a *method* called `clv`. You don't have such a method. You've got a *variable* called `clv`, but you don't "call" a variable.

The second problem is that if you really meant this:

```
setColorValue(clv);
```

then you'd be using incorrect arguments - `setColorValue` doesn't have one parameter of type `ColorValue`, it has three parameters, all `int`s.

Unfortunately it's not clear what you're *attempting* to do, so it's hard to advise you. *Perhaps* you mean this:

```
public abstract class Geometry 
{
    private String shapeId;
    private ColorValue colorValue;

    public Shape(String shapeId, int red, int green, int blue)
    {
        this.shapeId = shapeId;
        setColorValue(red, green, blue);
    }

    public ColorValue getColorValue()
    {
        return colorValue;
    }

    // Note the consistent order of the parameters - always red, green, blue.
    public void setColorValue(int red, int green, blue)
    {
        // Don't use System.exit() in the middle of a method! An exception
        // is the idiomatic way of reporting bad arguments.
        if (red == 0 || blue == 0 || green == 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("red green and blue must be non-zero");
        }
        colorValue = new ColorValue(red, green, blue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jon, yes I mistyped the variables, my apologies.  Yes that's what I had at first with the setColorValue:  setColorValue(red, green, blue).  But I need to create a new ColorValue object first using the values from the constructor.  Then use that new ColorValue object to send to the setColorValue method.

Comment: @wonu: But `setColorValue` doesn't *take* a `ColorValue` reference - it takes three `int` parameters.

Comment: Hmm..yes but it is supposed to take the three parameters from the constructor.  But I had to assign the new Object with the three parameters to the ColorValue variable. Should I change the set Method to reflect it you think?

Comment: @wonu: You need to make up your mind as to whether you want it to take *three* parameters or *one*. It can't be both, although you can overload it. Why do you think you need to create the new object in the constructor, instead of in the method? Have a look at my suggested code, and see whether there's anything you want to change about it.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the error:

```
public abstract class Geometry 
{
    private String shapeId;
    ColorValue colorValue;//ColorValue data member from the ColorValue.java class


    public Shape(String bodyid, int rd, int grn, int ble)
    {
        shapeId = bodyid;
        setColorValue(rd, grn, ble);
    }

    private ColorValue getColorValue()
    {
        return colorValue;
    }

    private void setColorValue(int redIn, int blueIn, int greenIn)
    {
        if(redIn == 0 || blueIn == 0 || greenIn == 0 )
        {
            System.out.println("The value entered in is null.  Please try again ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        colorValue = new ColorValue(redIn, greenIn, blueIn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have to create a new ColorValue object first...the pass that to the setColorValue method...how can I fit that in there?  Up top I have where I was trying to initiate a new object for it, but I can't seem to pass it to the set method...

Comment: Thanks Eng.Fouad that worked!!! thanks!  You can set the object outside of the constructor :)

Comment: Note that I would still change the parameter names, make the field private, and change the validation to throw an exception instead of calling System.exit.

Comment: Ah..okay yes I'll make that change now Jon.  Thanks again for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Your declared `setColorValue()` method takes 3 int parameters, but you are trying to call it by (presumably) passing a single ColorValue object, created by a method called clv that doesn't exist.  Hence the signatures don't match and the symbol is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Your setColorValue method takes 3 ints yet your trying to pass it a ColorValue

```
setColorValue(int redIn, int blueIn, int greenIn)
```

to use this method you need to do something like

```
public Shape(String bodyid, int rd, int grn, int ble)
{
   setColorValue(rd, grn, ble);
}
```

or if you want to pass it a ColorValue object

```
public Shape(String bodyid, int rd, int grn, int ble)
{
   ColorValue clv = new ColorValue(rd, grn, ble);
   setColorValue(clv);
}

private void setColorValue(ColorValue clv)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

or you can do this which will create the object and pass it to the method in the one step:

```
public Shape(String bodyid, int rd, int grn, int ble)
{
   setColorValue(new ColorValue(rd, grn, ble));
}
```

At the moment you seem to have a combination of lots of these.

Comment: Yes I tried the setColorValue(clv) once before and I got this error below.  Its looking for three values/parameters but I passed that in from the new object to the clv variable.  Not sure why I need to pass it in again?  It's a little confusing...
method setColorValue in class can not be applied to given types. 
required: finals.ColorValue,finals.ColorValue
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length